# How to First order logic procedure convert Convert to Conjunctive Normal Form ?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, artificial-intelligence

How to below this First order logic  procedure  convert Convert them into Conjunctive Normal Form ?

> Ɐx [[employee(x) ꓥ ¬[PST(x) ꓦ PWO(x)]] → work(x)]

I strive to do this below step ,

**i.    S1: Eliminate ↔**

```
This step does not apply as there are no negations in front
```

**ii.   S2: Eliminate →**

```
Ɐx [ [employee(x) ꓥ ¬[PST(x) ꓦ PWO(x)]] ꓦ work(x)]
```

**iii.  S3: Push negation in**

```
Ɐx [ [employee(x) ꓥ ¬[PST(x) ꓦ PWO(x)]] ꓦ work(x)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Step ii should read:  $$\forall x [\lnot [employee(x) \land ¬[PST(x) \lor PWO(x)]] \lor work(x)]\tag{ii}$$ $$\equiv \forall x[[\lnot employee(x) \lor [PST(x) \lor PWO(x)]] \lor work(x)]\tag{DeMorgan's}$$
$$ \equiv \forall x\big(\lnot employee(x) \lor PST(x) \lor PWO(x) \lor work(x)\big)\tag{associativity}$$

Now, if $x\in\{\text{John}, \text{Julie}, \text{Jessica}\}$, we can write the above in conjunctive normal form as follows:

$$\big(\lnot employee(\text{John}) \lor PST(\text{John}) \lor PWO(\text{John}) \lor work(\text{John})\big) \\ \land \big(\lnot employee(\text{Julie}) \lor PST(\text{Julie}) \lor PWO(\text{Julie}) \lor work(\text{Julie})\big) \\ \land \big(\lnot employee(\text{Jessica}) \lor PST(\text{Jessica}) \lor PWO(\text{Jessica}) \lor work(\text{Jessica})\big)$$

If there  are 211 employees, each identified with a unique ID from the set $S= \{1, 2, ..., 210, 211\}$, then we can further consolidate, into conjunctive normal form, as follows.

$\Huge{\land}$ $_{i \in S} \big(\lnot employee(i) \lor PST(i) \lor PWO(i) \lor work(i)\big)$

Comment: apologize , Please clarify this answer. example step by step

Comment: I did proceed, step by step.  $p \to q \equiv \lnot p \lor q$ (definition of implication).  $\lnot[p_1 \land \lnot p_2]\equiv \lnot p_1 \lor \lnot \lnot p_2 \equiv \lnot p_1 \lor p_2$ (By DeMorgan's and double negation).